# Can localStorage be viewed/used across computers?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, web-development-server

I'm trying to redirect input values from an HTML form and display them on a different page of the same website. I have been using localStorage to do this and it works on my computer, but I opened the webpage on another computer and the information was not stored. For example, I would submit firstName lastName into the HTML form and it would display firstName and lastName on the proper page but on a different computer the page would be empty unless I input those values into the form again on that computer. I thought localStorage works for pages in the same domain?

I was hoping to display the input values somehow without using server-side programming since I am not very familiar with it.

This is a code snippet from w3schools but this is basically what I have been doing, however setItem() would be in the html file for the page with the form and getItem() would be in the html file for the page I want to display the values:

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", some value);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 
localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

If localStorage does not work, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: Localstorage is per browser on the computer. It can also be cleared by the user, normally in settings under "clear site data"

Comment: How would it know that it's you on the second computer?

Comment: @Zak He's not using different servers, he's using different clients.

Comment: What do you think the "local" in "local storage" means?

Comment: Local means your hard disk. What you need is a database. SQL is not hard to find info on.

Answer (score 0):

No, localStorage is per browser on a machine. You could use URLs to manage page history and hand those off to your DB, store them on a users profile.