# Html text editing and saving

Tags: html

I have a website where I can save texts but only on `localStorage` so if I open it in another device there will be different or nothing. I want it so if I rewrite the text on my PC for example, it will be the same on other devices.

```
document.getElementById("save").addEventListener('click', 
function() {
 localStorage.setItem("text", document.getElementById('example- 
 one').innerHTML);
```

The current code saves on local when I push the button but I want it to save on host or on my main PC. I'm thinking of something similar to google docs but without logging in and out.

Comment: Please go through this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56435457/can-localstorage-be-viewed-used-across-computers

Comment: I guess you want the changes to be there for a particular user, not for just any one? You need a backend with a database and a user registration/login system - this cannot be done by the browsers/client alone which can only manage local storage (local means local, local to the browser/to the machine).

Comment: This will introduce XSS vulnerabilities. Good to read for everyone => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: I need database even If I only want to save text files? Or is there any other methods?

Comment: Are you the only user? Save the file on your host and open it and write to it as much as you want. Otherwise you need to keep track of who owns which files somehow. The tags on your question do not match your code, btw.